# Euclidean geometry with ruler and compass

Tags: euclidean-geometry

I was wondering, is there any book out there that is of the style of Euclid's Elements ? One which you have to use a compass and ruler for certain propositions like building a triangle, etc. Or would it be better to study the elements directly ? Also, is there any development (research) in this field ?

Thank you!

Comment: Here are a nice set of videos on [Euclid's elements](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zdofiH5HncU)

Comment: Well, Gauss showed that you can make a regular 17-gon (heptadecagon, I think, for the linguistics people out there), but not almost anything else. And also there's the result that anything done with a ruler and compass can be done with compass alone, or with a ruler alone plus one pre-existing circle. So I think that counts as research.

Comment: Ok, but you have no idea of a book that is the equivalent of the elements???